# What does 'nls' in nls_date_format stand for?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

For example:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss';
```

changes the date format for the session.

**What is `nls` here?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

National Language Support (because Americans have this weird idea of using MM-DD-YYYY as a date format, and different languages have different words for their months).

Answer (score 9):

The Oracle [Concepts Guide for 11.2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/cncptdev.htm#CNCPT7664) says the following (The note is of particular interest):

> **Globalization Support Environment**
>
> The globalization support environment
>   includes the client application and
>   the database. You can control
>   language-dependent operations by
>   setting parameters and environment
>   variables on the client and server,
>   which may exist in separate locations.
>
> Note: *In previous releases, Oracle
>   referred to globalization support
>   capabilities as National Language
>   Support (NLS) features. NLS is
>   actually a subset of globalization
>   support and provides the ability to
>   choose a national language and store
>   data in a specific character set.*
>
> Oracle Database provides globalization
>   support for features such as:
>
> - Native languages and territories
> - Local formats for date, time,
>     numbers, and currency
> - Calendar systems (Gregorian,
>     Japanese, Imperial, Thai Buddha, and
>     so on)
> - Multiple character sets,
>     including Unicode
> - Character semantics